# Azure AD - Issue with Common endpoint performance

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have a multi-tenant Azure Application using the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint.

This application is registered using the new App Registration Portal with an account from an Office 365 tenant registered in Europe.

We also have server instances (using Azure Web App) in multiple regions fronted by Azure Traffic Manager in order to serve our users as close as possible to their geographical location.

However, we've been getting reports of slow sign-in speed from our customers outside Europe.

While investigating, we noticed a significant difference in the duration of the calls to `/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` based on the geographical location of our server-side instances:

[image]

As indicated by the graph, requests from Europe take an average of 550 milliseconds but from any other region, the requests are an order of magnitute slower.

Is this a limitation of the platform or is there something we could do to improve the performance of these requests?